# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot") returning null when called in a WebRole

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, webrole

I have a method (in a separated class library) which is called by a WebRole and a WorkerRole. This method contains the path of a file, which is returned using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot")`, as follows:

```
private string FooPath()    
{
    string appRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot");
    return Path.Combine(appRoot + @"\", @"approot\file.foo");
}
```

When I call this method from a WorkerRole the path is returned normally. But when I call it from a WebRole I get `null`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I am using APNS-Sharp to send push messages to iOS and it requires a .p12 certificate in order to work. Currently I have the .p12 in the root of my class library (which is called by both WebRole and WorkerRole). But the point is: Why `RoleRoot` returns null when I call it from a WebRole but returns the path when I call from a WorkerRole?

Comment: Are you sure you need to locate files in `RoleRoot`? It seems to be a wrong idea for me.

Comment: I need to load a certificate. Would blob be a better idea?

Comment: can you make it a little bit more clear what are you going to do with this file? Who will read it and who will write it? Probably all you need is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.getlocalresource.aspx

Comment: I have just edited the question. :)

Comment: regarding your question quick googling results in this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/25/role-environment-variables-in-full-iis-web-role-and-in-hwc-web-role.aspx

Comment: Thanks! That helped me to understand my problem and I even came with the solution. Can you post as answer? :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RoleRoot` returns false for WebRole because the WebRole uses IIS, just like a normal website. That's why it's difficult to get Environment Variables from a WebRole.

In order to get the path properly I had to use the classic Server.MapPath and reference the `bin` folder, instead of `approot`:

```
private string FooPathWebRole()    
{
    string appRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\");
    return Path.Combine(appRoot + @"\", @"bin\file.foo");
}
```

For the WorkerRole nothing has changed:

```
private string FooPathWorkerRole()    
{
    string appRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot");
    return Path.Combine(appRoot + @"\", @"approot\file.foo");
}
```

In addition, I found out that Azure doesn't import p12 certificates. I would have to transform it into another format, which I don't believe would work for me. So, the best option is to place them on the root of the application and mark its **Build Action** to **Content**.

Comment: Note you need to add a ref to System.IO for the Path.Combine command.

Comment: See http://blog.toddysm.com/2011/03/what-environment-variables-can-you-use-in-windows-azure.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried from webrole and it works for me. I place it at the OnStart() code of the web role, which is called by WaIISHost

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a certificate, you could try the advice in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/01/29/installing-certificates-in-windows-azure-vms.aspx

Linked from [How do I import a public certificate to Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029104/how-do-i-import-a-public-certificate-to-windows-azure)